# Disable Pull To Refresh in Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

We have developed a lightning aura component for desktop and mobile views. But we're not able to disable the Pull-To-Refresh feature, impacting the data loss. Is there any specific code to disable this feature from the mobile app?

```
({
    afterRender: function (component, helper) {
        alert('Hi');
        this.superAfterRender();
        var targetEl = component.find("mainContainer").getElement();
        alert('targetEl'+targetEl);
        targetEl.addEventListener(
            "touchmove", 
            helper.scrollStopPropagation, 
            true // we use capture!
        );
    }
})
```

Please help us resolve this asap as we have a timeline for production, we'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Disable Pull To Refresh is officially supported for Aura and LWC since Summer 22.

> Pull-to-refresh can be disabled by firing a CustomEvent in JavaScript, which you can do from both Lightning web components and Aura components

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_disable_pull_to_refresh_in_mobile_components.htm&type=5&release=238

For LWC, there is [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_disable_pull_to_refresh_in_the_mobile_app) but I could not find any for Aura.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable response Christian, I have also gone through the document earlier, but only it's present for LWC.
I want to do it on AURA COMPONENT, Please let me know if you get any more findings

Answer (score 0):

The pull-to-refresh is a standard feature for Salesforce mobile app and there is no official functionality to prevent this behavior.

There is also an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgJ6UAJ/allow-disable-of-pull-to-refresh-on-lightning-components) logged for this feature request.

I checked that there is an internal investigation #W-9547355 logged with the concerned salesforce product team to have this functionality implemented. Please consider upvoting the idea so that this feature implementation can be prioritized.