# Disable Pull To Refresh in Salesforce Mobile App with Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, mobile, salesforce-mobile-app

This questions is already answered for LWC here: [Disable Pull To Refresh in Salesforce Mobile App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382475/disable-pull-to-refresh-in-salesforce-mobile-app)

I have tried the answer from Christian Szandor Knapp and it works well.

No I would prefer to do the very same, just using an Aura Component instead of a LWC.

How can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried using the same approach? The release notes seem to indicate it should work the same and I would assume it would considering it's a custom event.  `Pull-to-refresh can be disabled by firing a CustomEvent in JavaScript, which you can do from both Lightning web components and Aura components. `

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I don't know how to setup the params and fire the CustomEvent in Aura Components like in the example for LWC. This seems to be different. I don't want to fiddle around if some knows already how to do so. That means my question could be rephrased: how to parametrize and fire the event in Aura. In Aura Events seem to be created as separate Metadata artifacts. Do I really have to create that? I would like to fire as pure-JS and avoid Metadata clutter. If I create an Aura Event though, how exactly it has to be named an parametrized and fired?

Answer (score 1):

The event mentioned in release notes (and [example shown](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_disable_pull_to_refresh_in_the_mobile_app) for LWC) is a DOM event that you can simply send in Aura just like LWC (no need to configure a custom Aura event).

In your controller of your Aura component - you can dispatch the event as shown below on initialization

```javascript
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var detail = {};

        detail["isPullToRefreshEnabled"] = false;
        detail["isPullToShowMoreEnabled"] = false;
        
        var updateScrollSettingsEvent = new CustomEvent("updateScrollSettings", {
            detail: detail,
            bubbles: true,
            composed: true
        });

        dispatchEvent(updateScrollSettingsEvent);
    }
})
```

I was able to use the above in a barebones Aura component and confirm the pull down was disabled on Mobile app (Android).